# php - Passing arrays to $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm working on a PHP app that has one (of many) arrays vital to the operation of the program. I need to keep the contents of this array intact in between page loads. I know that `$_POST` can be used to retain most data types over page loads, but how does one put an array... In an array?

The array is a simple one, but the amount of indices it has depends on user input - it can range from anywhere between 1 to 50.

Is there any way I can retain an array's data between page loads with `$_POST`?

Comment: You should use `$_SESSION`, not POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear. Passing variables between pages should be held in a `$_SESSION` not a `$_POST` variable. Storing an array in a session variable is the same as saving any variable to a session variable.

```
$session_start();
$_SESSION['my_array'] = array('one', 'two', 'three');
foreach($_SESSION['my_array'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had no clue you could set an array index's value as an array like that. I'm giving it a go right now.

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1 in client/server development: *Never trust the client*.

You're better off storing the array in PHP's session state, or serializing it out to disk.

Fortunately, it's easy:

```
$_SESSION['someKey]' = $myArray;
```

There is another problem with your proposal of storing it in the page: what happens if the user uses the Back button and resubmits or otherwise breaks your page-ordering? By storing state on the client you cannot rely on it anymore.